# BigQuery backreference

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

How would I do a backreference in BigQuery? The current regex I have is:

- [`(["'])?(?:[01](?:.0)?|true|false)\1?`](https://regex101.com/r/lL3ABx/1)

When I run

```
SELECT REGEXP_CONTAINS("true", r'''(["'])?(?:[01](?:.0)?|true|false)\1?''')
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot parse regular expression: invalid escape sequence: \1

What would be the proper way to do this? (Adding another `\` 'fixes' the error, but that backreference doesn't work -- the above should return `true`).

Comment: Seems backreferences aren't supported in re2 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery and re2 do not support backreferences. You can use a slightly looser regex like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_CONTAINS("true", r'''["']?(true|false|0(.0)?|1(.0)?)["']?''')
```

Note that something like `"true'` would match, so if it needs to be very strict, you'll need to handle all cases and not just be able to get away with `['"]?`